# Timeseries analysis with partially overlapping date ranges

Tags: time-series, missing-data, overlapping-data

I am working with a dataset of car/vehicle measurements at a Target location. In this dataset, there are multiple providers that give measurements about the number of vehicles at that Target (based on cars/devices in their sample) . However, because each provider gives data from a different sample of vehicles, they provide measurements at different levels (and thus units). Further, they provide these measurements over different periods of time. To fully clarify the question, consider this case:

Provider A: Sample size (10000), Jan/2020 to March 2021 
Provider B: Sample size (50000), Jan/2019 to May 2022

Thus, I am attempting to merge these provider measurements together in order to provide the strongest estimate of trip activity at Target given their overlap/sample size. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon @Augustine, looking at what you post, the first step would be to put the date column as an index, after that, do a treatment from the initial date to the final date. Using:

[pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)
[pandas.DataFrame.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

Creating a new data index, you make a reindex for this current index, and the existing indexes will be overwritten, not losing the lines of either A or B.

After doing this for the two sets, you have to create a new date index, to correct any missing dates in this period of the two sets.

To merge you an index based on dates, to merge I usually use pandas merge, but that depends a lot on your set if it has a very high dimension. This can take a lot of processing. Then do it with concat using axis 0 or 1, to see if I've already managed to meet your needs. If that doesn't work, try with merge, it has more features for merging. It's a little difficult to say which one would be better because I don't have something to test here.

[merge, concat, join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/user_guide/merging.html)